# How to delete record using SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to delete the record from Sqlite, My table name is "TABLE_NAME" and column name
is "COLUMN1", I pass the string value from MyTable.java to mySqliteHelper.java.
I need to delete this record which value I pass. Here is my sample code.
Give me hint or suggestion. Any help is appreciated.

MyTable.java

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Delete Profile");
    alert.setMessage("You want to delete this profile?");       
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {         
            MySQLiteHelper m=new MySQLiteHelper(getBaseContext());
            m.deleteBName(other);   
            deleteMessage();
        }
    });
```

MySQLitHelper.java

```
public void deleteBName(String keyword) 
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN1+"="+keyword, null);   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "column_name=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(keyword)});
```

Refer to documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: db.delete() return the rows affected..so for debugging , do `int temp = db.delete(...);` and check if the rows are getting affected or not,, otherwise it might be minor problem with spelling or something....  btw the second parameter must be as it is, like `COLUMN1+"=?"` no reference to `keyword` here...

Comment: Hey thanks! it's working.actually i enter wrong column name....Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
dbHelper.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { myName })
```